# Download a Excel from GiThub into Excel

Tags: excel, github, m

I would like with M to build a script to connect to an Excel file.

One example:
https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.xlsx

Tann

Answer (score 0):

You want the URL to the raw file rather than that web page.

```
Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents(
"https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.xlsx?raw=true"
))
```

Full example that can be pasted into the Advanced Editor:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/blob/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.xlsx?raw=true")),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"iso_code", type text}, {"continent", type text}, {"location", type text}, {"date", type date}, {"total_cases", Int64.Type}, {"new_cases", Int64.Type}, {"new_cases_smoothed", type number}, {"total_deaths", Int64.Type}, {"new_deaths", Int64.Type}, {"new_deaths_smoothed", type number}, {"total_cases_per_million", type number}, {"new_cases_per_million", type number}, {"new_cases_smoothed_per_million", type number}, {"total_deaths_per_million", type number}, {"new_deaths_per_million", type number}, {"new_deaths_smoothed_per_million", type number}, {"reproduction_rate", type number}, {"icu_patients", type any}, {"icu_patients_per_million", type any}, {"hosp_patients", type any}, {"hosp_patients_per_million", type any}, {"weekly_icu_admissions", type any}, {"weekly_icu_admissions_per_million", type any}, {"weekly_hosp_admissions", type any}, {"weekly_hosp_admissions_per_million", type any}, {"new_tests", type any}, {"total_tests", type any}, {"total_tests_per_thousand", type any}, {"new_tests_per_thousand", type any}, {"new_tests_smoothed", type any}, {"new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand", type any}, {"positive_rate", type any}, {"tests_per_case", type any}, {"tests_units", type text}, {"total_vaccinations", type any}, {"new_vaccinations", type any}, {"total_vaccinations_per_hundred", type any}, {"new_vaccinations_per_million", type any}, {"stringency_index", type number}, {"population", Int64.Type}, {"population_density", type number}, {"median_age", type number}, {"aged_65_older", type number}, {"aged_70_older", type number}, {"gdp_per_capita", type number}, {"extreme_poverty", type any}, {"cardiovasc_death_rate", type number}, {"diabetes_prevalence", type number}, {"female_smokers", type any}, {"male_smokers", type any}, {"handwashing_facilities", type number}, {"hospital_beds_per_thousand", type number}, {"life_expectancy", type number}, {"human_development_index", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```